# identify if IP addresses in list A exist within a list of IP ranges in list B

Tags: shell-script, ip, diff, bsd

I have 2 lists, one containing all 32 bit IP addresses, and the other is a list of ip ranges and other IP addresses. I need to find if each IP within list A exists in any IP range or address in list B. The end result would be to display the addresses from list A that do not exists in list B. 
This would be easy using diff if the IP ranges were not involved. The list itself contains nearly 10,000 lines so to go through this manually would take forever.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: So far I have my 2 lists and I used diff -wy listA listB

Comment: This only worked on the 32 bit to 32 bit addresses but I dont know how to check if a 32 bit address exists within a number of IP ranges

Comment: My only other idea was to create a list containing only the IP ranges and explode them in a much longer list using echo  10.0.0.{1..200} | tr ' ' '\n' manuall for each one of them

Comment: I used 10.0.0.{1..200} just as an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script does the trick on Linux/Bash. I'm not sure if it's bug-free. Comment if you want any explanation.

```
#!/bin/bash

# The script prints addresses from one file that are NOT
# in the ranges provided in another file.

# $1 is the file with addresses to check
# $2 is the file that holds the ranges
## in format x.x.x.x-y.y.y.y or as a single IP, one per line.

### Variables ###

inFile="$1"
rangesFile="$2"
typeset -a rangesLow rangesHigh #arrays of int
rangesCount=


### Functions ###

toInt () {
    printf "%d\n" $(($1*256*256*256 + $2*256*256 + $3*256 + $4))
}

readRanges () {
    while IFS=- read -a range
    do
        IFS=. read -a low <<< "${range[0]}"
        [ -z "${range[1]}" ] && range[1]="${range[0]}"
        IFS=. read -a high <<< "${range[1]}"
        rangesLow+=( $(toInt "${low[@]}") )
        rangesHigh+=( $(toInt "${high[@]}") )
    done < "$rangesFile"
    rangesCount=${#rangesLow[@]}
}

singleCheck () {
    # $1 is the address to check.
    # $2 and $3 are the bounds, low and high.
    # Returns 0 if NOT in range.

    [[ $1 -ge $2 ]] && [[ $1 -le $3 ]] && return 1
    # To invert the logic of the script, instead of the line above
    ## use this one:
    # [[ $1 -ge $2 ]] && [[ $1 -le $3 ]] || return 1
    return 0
}

addressCheck () {
    # The function takes in 4 octets of an IP as four positional parameters.
    # Returns 1 if IP is in any range.
    # If not in range, the address is printed to stdout.
    local address
    address=$(toInt "$@")
    for ((i=0; i<rangesCount ; i++)) # Loop for all ranges.
    do
        singleCheck "$address" "${rangesLow[$i]}" "${rangesHigh[$i]}" || return 1 
    done    
    printf "%d.%d.%d.%d\n" "$@"
}

checkAll () {
    while IFS=. read -a toCheck
    do
        addressCheck "${toCheck[@]}"
    done < "$inFile"
}

main () {
    readRanges
    checkAll
}

### Execute ###

main
```

Based on hymie's brilliant thought.

Comment: I am on a BSD machine and only have bourne shell (sh) . Will this still work ?

Comment: @Steve I'm afraid not.

Comment: Well I am going to find a redhat box and test this out in the morning. THANK YOU !!!!! I will get back to you and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Would i simply rename my to files as inFile
rangesFile  ? Also, within the ranges file, it also include 32 bit addresses beside address ranges. Will this work for addresses listed without a range ?

Comment: @Steve You don't have to rename any files. Just call in this order: `./script ips ranges`. But as it is, it needs ranges. I'll try to fix this in a mo.

Comment: @Steve I added one line that should do it. Notice the ranges if present need to be in this format: `x.x.x.x-y.y.y.y`.

Comment: Tomas 100% success !!!! A most triumphant program !!! You totally ROCK ! thank you !!!!!

Comment: Tomas, would it be possible to reverse engineer this and display the matches instead of the delta's ?

Comment: @Steve Yes, it's quite easy. But as I understand it now, it's a homework. So I can only give you a hint that you need to change not more than five characters in the script.

Comment: Tomas, I have not yet figured this out. I DO see                                         
[[ $1 -ge $2 ]] && [[ $1 -le $3 ]] && return 1
    return 0                                                                                                  
IF $1 is greater than $2 AND $1 is less than $3 I have the match I am looking for yet I need return 1 to stdout...kind of the reverse so I tried it and it did not work. This script is more advanced than where I am at so far. What does the @ symbol indicate ? I am trying to break this down but I don't use functions yet. Can you shed a little light?

Comment: @Steve `@` means you address someone in the convo. It autocompletes when you press Tab. As for the problem, you found the right spot, but you don't understand the logic in the script. `return` doesn't print anything. It's the function's return call. `return 1` is a standard way of signalling the function fails. While `return 0` is the standard way of signalling function's success. If there's no explicit `return` in a function, the function returns the exit status of the last command executed in it. You can use `$?` to see the exit status of the last command executed.

Comment: @Steve If you change the shebang in the first line to `#!/bin/bash -x`, you'll see what's going on step by step.

Comment: @Steve `@` in Bash :-) means many things. In this context: `"$@"` it stands for all positional parameters, ie. $1 $2 etc. In arrays it means all elements.

Comment: @Steve The `addressCheck` function had a wrong description. Sorry, now it's ok.

Comment: thanks for the clarification...i am still on this trying and testing yet failing

Comment: to reverse this and get only the IP's that exist within the range, I made it say $1 is less than $2 AND $1 is greater than $3                                         [[ $1 -lt $2 ]] && [[ $1 -gt $3 ]] && return 1
    return 0        This is logical yet did not work as it displayed the entire IP list

Comment: main is called to execute readranges and checkall. Readranges function is used to create the high-low ranges in a usable format. The checkall function calls the addresscheck function which calls the singlecheck function. The script is almost pure functions which is really cool. This isnt for a class, this is a personal challenge which will make future tasks a lot earier when dealing with dhcp scopes. I have never used functions before but will take a class and learn it. For the time being, I posted above what I have done with no success. I have also used the -x but still cant see my error.

Comment: addresscheck is actually the function I need to modify isnt it ??

Comment: Ok because I had to get this completed today, I appended the original scripts output to the ips file, then sorted it and ran uniq -u and got the results i needed. Yes, this was no the most righteous solution but I was pressed for time. Can you share with me what I SHOULD have done ??

Comment: @Steve If the ranges are well formated, that is if $3 > $2, your condition is dead, as $1 can't be both bigger than $3 and smaller than $1. And this condition, as you do know, is the filter that filters out what you don't want to be printed. The key here is to use the logical alternative. The alternative is `||`. Think of where to use it. If you can't find a solution, take a look at the right place in my updated answer.

Comment: I actually did replace the && with || but in the wrong spot   [[ $1 -ge $2 ]] || [[ $1 -le $3 ]] && return 1

Comment: @Steve For beginners the short forms with && and || may be difficult to encompas. So I'd advise to use the full `if ... fi` form. For both check logical structures using `true` and `false`, for example: `true && false && true || echo ok`. (What did you expect?) Also try to think in terms of tests and debugging. Then use `-x` and minimal but sufficient testing material to see if your logic is complete. Even very good programmers make mistakes.

Comment: I understand and thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a shell script, but a program should be able to convert both lists from dotted-quad IP addresses into single integers, and then compare the numbers with standard greater-than less-than.

```
i = (first octet * 256*256*256) + (second octet * 256*256)
  + (third octet * 256) + (fourth octet)
```